# deployment error occurred while uploading app file (ords.war) on glassfish3 server

Tags: java, oracle, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

I've just installed the glassfish server version 3 and I've uploaded the ords.war file to deploy it on the web server please if anyone have the answer leave it in the comment.
Thanks in advance.

```
Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:null
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.weld.DeploymentImpl.loadBeanDeploymentArchive(DeploymentImpl.java:435)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.DeploymentStructures.getOrCreateBeanDeployment(DeploymentStructures.java:37)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ExtensionBeanDeployer.deployBean(ExtensionBeanDeployer.java:82)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startInitialization(WeldStartup.java:378)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startInitialization(WeldBootstrap.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:225)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:131)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:328)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.utils.ResourceUtil.runCommand(ResourceUtil.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.admin.rest.resources.TemplateListOfResource.createResource(TemplateListOfResource.java:134)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.lambda$static$0(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:191)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:493)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:415)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:277)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:316)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:289)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

ORDS support on glassfish was [deprecated in version 17.4](https://docs.oracle.com/database/ords-17/AELIG/GUID-F3B3C380-DC51-41FD-8A15-966F9B5FBCF3.htm#AELIG-GUID-F3B3C380-DC51-41FD-8A15-966F9B5FBCF3) and [desupported in 19.1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/19.2/aelig/changes-this-release-oracle-rest-data-services-installation-configuration-and-development-guide.html#GUID-47550118-21F6-4988-9A8C-116314315778). If you are using ORDS 19.1 or later, it will need to be run using Apache Tomcat, Oracle WebLogic, or in standalone mode.